# Clear cache files older than 30 minutes

Tags: python, file-system, cache

This is what I came up with to delete files not modified within the last 30 minutes from a subdirectory named `cache`.

```
'''
Clear cache files older than 30 minutes.
'''

import os
import time

outer = os.getcwd()
cache = os.path.join(outer, 'cache')
count = 0
for f in os.listdir(cache):
        f = os.path.join(cache, f)
        use_by = time.time() - 30 * 60
        if os.path.getatime(f) < use_by:
                os.remove(f)
                count += 1
print("Removed {} files.".format(count))
```

Would love input as to how to make it more concise, as well as other improvements or details I might have missed.

Had tried to put `os.getcwd()` within `os.path.join` but got:

```
  File "/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/bin/../lib/python2.7/posixpath.py",         line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
> for f in os.listdir(cache):
>         # ...
>         use_by = time.time() - 30 * 60
>         if os.path.getatime(f) < use_by:
>                 # ...
> ```

Consider this:

```
use_by = time.time() - 30 * 60
for f in os.listdir(cache):
        # ...
        if os.path.getatime(f) < use_by:
                # ...
```

In this version, `use_by` is set only once, before the loop begins,
which is slightly more efficient.
Unless, you really want the timing to be re-evaluated in every iteration.

---

It can be error-prone and lead to nasty bugs to re-assign the loop variable (as well as method arguments), like here:

> ```
> for f in os.listdir(cache):
>         f = os.path.join(cache, f)
> ```

And in any case, I would recommend using more meaningful variable names, for example:

```
for filename in os.listdir(basedir):
    path = os.path.join(basedir, filename)
```

---

The code you posted sounds like a good idea.
It could be turned into a reusable, general function with parameters:

- `basedir`: base directory to clean
- `limit`: time limit to use, in minutes

Something like this:

```
def wipe_unused(basedir, limit):
    """
    Remove files in *basedir* not accessed within *limit* minutes

    :param basedir: directory to clean
    :param limit: minutes
    """
    atime_limit = time.time() - limit
    count = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(basedir):
        path = os.path.join(basedir, filename)
        if os.path.getatime(path) < atime_limit:
            os.remove(path)
            count += 1
    print("Removed {} files.".format(count))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wipe_unused(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cache'), 30 * 60)
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you, man. Great tips! It's actually quite silly that I was reassigning the var AND calling time.time() on each pass.